# Vaughan's identity, a didactic example

Tags: analytic-number-theory, trigonometric-series, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function

I know that **Vaughan's identity** is one of the methods used in **analityc number theory**, I would like see an example, I say a simple example of application of this theorem for encourage to study the statement of such theorem, and perhaps its proof. I say this cited theorem, **Vaughan's identity**, concerning

$$\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda(n)f(n),$$ 
where $\Lambda(n)$ is the **von Mangoldt function**, and for example (you can choose other function $f(x)$ for this didactic example)

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
e^{2\pi ig(n)},  & \text{if $1\leq n\leq N$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
for an easy function $g(n)$. I hope that this last has sense for you. You can choose other functions to show an easy application of **Vaughan's identity**.

> **Question.** Can you give a didactic example of an application, for a choice of $g(n)$ or other $f(x)$, of cited theorem? I would like to see easy computations for previous identity in RHS, if you can use Vinogradov notation $\ll$  in some computations of such summands in RHS, for illustrate the application of the theorem and how you deduce some easy computations, you are welcome. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Do you mean [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaughan's_identity) ? Perhaps you'll find terry Tao's essay on it interesting, see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/vaughans-identity/).

Comment: I did a mistake in my previous reference, sorry me @DietrichBurde the reference of such theorem is the same of your cite  Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks other time for the user who gave a first answer, and references for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first example for $f(n)$, namely $f(n)=n^{-s}$ for complex $s$ with $Re(s)>1$. Then we obtain the partial sums of the Dirichlet series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Lambda(n)n^{-s}=-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)},
$$
involving $\zeta(s)$ and its derivative. For more substantial applications of Vaughan's identity see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55274/other-applications-of-vaughans-lemma).

Comment: I accept yur words, but now this say few to me, I will do a comparision of all summand in RHS. Very thanks much.